# How to export database from Amazon RDS PostreSql to my local machine?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

How to export the postresql database from aws rds in a very simplest way, so that i can import that file into my local machine?

Comment: Connect db with a tool like pgAdmin for backup? Gotta make sure to allow access from your local computer too if not already.

Comment: You could be looking for [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html) utility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pg dump. Be sure that the the host running pg dump runs with the same version as the RDS server instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).